# Javascript function not returning a value

Tags: javascript, html, templates, smarty

I have a javascript function that check for a value from a text box and the if the text box is not blank it outputs a statement. The text box take a numeric value, i want to include that numeric value that is output to html.

here is the html

```
   <br><label id="cancelphoneLabel">1-800-555-1111</label>
   <br><label id="mdamountLabel">Monthly Donation:
<td>
    <input type="text" id="mdamountBox" style="width:50px;" name="md_amt" value="" placeholder="Monthly" onkeyup="monthlycheck()" autocomplete="off">

   <br><label id="mnthlychkdiscoLabel">&nbsp;</label>
```

and the Javascript

```
 function monthlycheck() {

var mnthchk = document.getElementById("mdamountBox").innerHTML; <---i want to pass the value of this box
var cancelPhone = document.getElementById("cancelphoneLabel").innerHTML;



if (mnthchk.value != "") {

    var newHTML = "<span style='color:#24D330'> Your Monthly pledge in the amount of $<label id='dollarLabel'>&nbsp;</label> is valid and will be deducted this time every month<br> untill you notify us of its cancellation by calling <label id='cancelphonelistLabel'>&nbsp;</label> </span>";

    document.getElementById("mnthlychkdiscoLabel").innerHTML = newHTML;
    document.getElementById("cancelphonelistLabel").innerHTML = cancelPhone;
    document.getElementById("dollarLabel").innerHTML = mnthchk;   <----passed to here
```

i cant get the value passed, it only shows blank, i can hardcode a value and will output fine, which is how the jsfiddle is currently http://jsfiddle.net/rn5HH/4/

thanks in advance

Comment: I've rolled the last edit back. Accepting an answer (which you've done) is how you mark a problem as solved on SO, not by changing the title. If you want to thank people, then please use the comments for that.

Comment: Quentin, Thank you for your input, however i didn't change the title as a way to mark it solved. I did that to make it easier for people to identify solved questions when sifting through search results from their favorite search engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input elements don't have child nodes, therefore `innerHTML` is blank. If you want to read their value, use the `value` property.

Answer (score 1):

Your line:

```
var mnthchk = document.getElementById("mdamountBox").innerHTML;
```

Should be:

```
var mnthchk = document.getElementById("mdamountBox");
```

Then you can get the value of the text input like this:

```
var newmnthchk = mnthchk.value;
```

Working JS Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/rn5HH/10/

Answer (score 0):

use `document.getElementById("mdamountBox").value`

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you are trying to get the innerHtml, where you want the value.  From your fiddle, just change this line:

```
var mnthchk = document.getElementById("mdamountBox").innerHTML;
```

...to this:

```
var mnthchk = document.getElementById("mdamountBox").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

check below code :

**HTML Code**

```
<br><label id="cancelphoneLabel">1-800-555-1111</label>
<br><label id="mdamountLabel">Monthly Donation:
<td>
    <input type="text" id="mdamountBox" style="width:50px;" name="md_amt" value="" placeholder="Monthly" onkeyup="monthlycheck()" autocomplete="off">

<br><label id="mnthlychkdiscoLabel">&nbsp;</label>
```

**Javascript Code**

```
function monthlycheck() {

var mnthchk = document.getElementById("mdamountBox").value;
var cancelPhone = document.getElementById("cancelphoneLabel").innerHTML;



if (mnthchk.value != "") {

    var newmnthchk = '5';
    newmnthchk = mnthchk;
    var newHTML = "<span style='color:#24D330'> Your Monthly pledge in the amount of $<label id='dollarLabel'>&nbsp;</label> is valid and will be deducted this time every month<br> untill you notify us of its cancellation by calling <label id='cancelphonelistLabel'>&nbsp;</label> </span>";

    document.getElementById("mnthlychkdiscoLabel").innerHTML = newHTML;
    document.getElementById("cancelphonelistLabel").innerHTML = cancelPhone;
    document.getElementById("dollarLabel").innerHTML = newmnthchk;

}
}
```

This is working code perfectly checked on Fiddle 
,you need to get DOM value using

```
var mnthchk = document.getElementById("mdamountBox").value;
```